# how can I use a variable as the axis coordinates in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

What I'm trying to do is show a function to be periodic on an interval of (-p, p), and what I have graphed is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$g(x)$},
    axis lines=middle, 
]
 axis lines=middle, 
\addplot [
    dashed,
    mark=*
    mark options={scale=2,solid},
    domain=-3:-1, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {(x<-1)*(x+2)};
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(-1,1)};
\addplot [
    dashed,
    domain=1:3, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    { !(x<1)*(x-2) };
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(-1,-1)};
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(1,1)};
\addplot [
    domain=-1:1, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {(!(x<-1) && (x<1))*x};
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(1,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way so that I can specify -p to equal -1 vertically and horizontally, and p to be equal to 1?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You may include all preamble, please?

Comment: Hi, we probably don't need your entire preamble, but it is always nice if you make a minimal, compilable example. In this case for example, the definition of `excl` is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xticklabel` and `yticklabel` to change how the ticks are printed. For example, `xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}p$}` means that the x-value in question, represented by `\tick`, is printed followed by a `p`.

If ticks at decimal values of `p` are fine, remove the lines

```
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{excl/.style={}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$g(x)$},
    axis lines=middle,
    xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}p$},
    yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}p$},
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1
]
 axis lines=middle, 
\addplot [
    dashed,
    mark=*
    mark options={scale=2,solid},
    domain=-3:-1, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {(x<-1)*(x+2)};
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(-1,1)};
\addplot [
    dashed,
    domain=1:3, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    { !(x<1)*(x-2) };
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(-1,-1)};
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(1,1)};
\addplot [
    domain=-1:1, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {(!(x<-1) && (x<1))*x};
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(1,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```